# Compile external library (Linux & Codeblock c++)

Tags: c++, linux, build, compilation, codeblocks

I have one c++ program and i use linux. To compile my program i need to include with command line the external lib that i need.

Example:

```
sudo g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o test main.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```

My question: It is possible compile the same code using only code blocks without using command line and lib includes. I already add the external lib in compiler and build options (linker settings) on codeblocks but it is not working. It's only work if i build and run the project from command line.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards.

Edit (Images of Build and compiler linker settings)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please post your output of "build log" and compare with your example.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Build log: g++  -o bin/Debug/test_mysql obj/Debug/main.o   /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.a /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.a /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a

I already have the same libs   /usr7lib/libmysqlcppconn.a,  /usr7lib/libmysqlcppconn.so and  /usr7lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a in compiler and build options (linker settings)

Comment: but if i try to build and compile from codeblock i have undefined referent in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.a

Comment: It seems that you try to link against dynamically and statically build libraries. Post your CB linker and compiler settings, please

Comment: @RMaster21 Post all relevant information in the body of your question, not in comments.

Comment: I edit the original post and put the images. Thanks

Comment: Ok, remove all libraries from the the left site. You have to insert `-lmysqlcppconn`under other linker options. Under search directories->Linker add the path to your libraries, in your case it must be `/usr/lib`. And try to compile again ;)

Comment: I need to change this on build and compiler at same time? I change both of us but now i'm getting the follow error: 

undefined reference to 'get_driver_instance'

Comment: thanks for the help. I already solve the last error. I need to stay with /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so in linker option on compiler :)